# Change all string fields to uppercase

Tags: java, javabeans, opencsv, apache-commons-beanutils

We are using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) to map CSV file to Java Bean. I want to make all String values to uppar case while mapping it to Java bean.
Suppose CSV contains following line

```
abc, 123, def, 123abc
```

while mapping it to bean it should be converted

```
ABC, 123, DEF, 123abc
```

I can go with reflection and have the desired result .But was looking for a solution through [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or Is there any feature in [Apache Bean Utils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) or any other similar library which converts all String fields from a bean to uppercase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an overridden `CsvToBean` implementation:

```
CsvToBean<BeanType> csv2Bean = new CsvToBean<BeanType>() {

    @Override
    protected Object convertValue(String value, PropertyDescriptor prop) {
        return super.convertValue(value.toUpperCase(), prop);
    }
};

List<BeanType> beanList = csv2Bean.parse(mappingStrategy, csvReader);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, [StringUtils.upperCase](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#upperCase%28java.lang.String%29)

```
if (StringUtils.isAlpha(value)) 
        {
            System.out.print("With uppercase " + StringUtils.upperCase(value));
        }
        else  // with number or anything with the word
        {
            System.out.print("Without uppercase " + value);
        }
```

or

```
System.out.println(""+(StringUtils.isAlpha(value) ? StringUtils.upperCase(value) : value));
```

Comment: As mentioned I will prefer not do it by myself.